# Comparing strings cause Runtime error

Tags: python

I'm comparing two GUIDs stored as strings in a script and it causes a runtime error. If I change the IF statement, it pushes the runtime error to the parent for loop. I can add an apparently useless for loop above the IF statement, and then it seems to fix the runtime error.

Here is the initial code where the error is encountered:

```
for row in cursor:
    print 'Remote len: '+str(len(agoFeatures))
    for agoFeature in agoFeatures:
        print 'row[2]: ', row[2], type(row[2]), len(row[2])
        print "agoFeature[a][s]: ", \
              agoFeatures['attributes']['SegmentID'].upper(), \
              type(agoFeature['attributes']['SegmentID'].upper()), \
              len(agoFeature['attributes']['SegmentID'].upper())
        localFeature = row[2]
        remoteFeature = '{'+agoFeature['attributes']['SegmentID'].upper()+'}'

        print 'localFeature: ', localFeature, type(localFeature), len(localFeature)
        print 'remoteFeature: ', remoteFeature, type(remoteFeature), len(remoteFeature)

        if localFeature == remoteFeature:
            print 'Local == Remote'
```

When ran, it will return this:

```
Remote len: 2
row[2]:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
Local == Remote
row[2]:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237 <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
Remote len: 2
row[2]:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetUpdates.py", line 262, in <module>
    main()
  File "GetUpdates.py", line 248, in main
    compareAGOFeaturesToLocal()
  File "GetUpdates.py", line 147, in compareAGOFeaturesToLocal
    if localFeature == remoteFeature:
RuntimeError
```

This compares the two GUIDs, and crashes on the IF statement after the 3rd comparison (7142 vs ED24). If I alter the IF statement to the following, it will continue until the end (7142 vs 7142), but crash on the for loop.

```
if str(localFeature) == str(remoteFeature):
    print 'Local == Remote'
```

Result:

```
Remote len: 2
row[2]:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
Local == Remote
row[2]:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237 <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
Remote len: 2
row[2]:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
row[2]:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237 <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
Local == Remote
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetUpdates.py", line 262, in <module>
    main()
  File "GetUpdates.py", line 248, in main
    compareAGOFeaturesToLocal()
  File "GetUpdates.py", line 137, in compareAGOFeaturesToLocal
    for agoFeature in agoFeatures:
RuntimeError
```

I assumed that there was something in the text that was causing an issue. I removed the str from the IF statement, and added a for loop to print each character from remoteFeature.

```
for row in cursor:
    print 'Remote len: '+str(len(agoFeatures))
    for agoFeature in agoFeatures:
        print 'row[2]: ', row[2], type(row[2]), len(row[2])
        print "agoFeature[a][s]: ", \
              agoFeatures['attributes']['SegmentID'].upper(), \
              type(agoFeature['attributes']['SegmentID'].upper()), \
              len(agoFeature['attributes']['SegmentID'].upper())
        localFeature = row[2]
        remoteFeature = '{'+agoFeature['attributes']['SegmentID'].upper()+'}'

        print 'localFeature: ', localFeature, type(localFeature), len(localFeature)
        print 'remoteFeature: ', remoteFeature, type(remoteFeature), len(remoteFeature)

        for i, char in enumerate(remoteFeature):
                i, ord(char), char

        if localFeature == remoteFeature:
            print 'Local == Remote'
```

I removed the print statement since it does not print anything useful (just shows each expected character). The added for loop does not do anything, but DOES allow it to complete successfully:

```
Remote len: 2
row[2]:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
Local == Remote
row[2]:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237 <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
Remote len: 2
row[2]:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {ED24C58B-253F-4D8A-8C1E-EBFFC57B4FDD} <type 'unicode'> 38
row[2]:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
agoFeature[a][s]:  714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237 <type 'unicode'> 36
localFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
remoteFeature:  {714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237} <type 'unicode'> 38
Local == Remote
Start: 2014-08-14 11:41:20.628000
End: 2014-08-14 11:41:24.685000
Difference: 0:00:04.057000
```

Printing the start/end/difference is handled at the end of the script. Are there any ideas why this error is happening, or how I can handle it? I don't like the extra for loop since it's such a hack.

Comment: Have you truncated the traceback error message, When you get a RuntimeError it normally says more than just an error.

Comment: This is a weird error, and there's no reason you should need to hack your way around it. I wonder if your Python install is messed up in some way. Is there a possibility to try this on a different box?

Comment: I just tried it on another computer, one with Windows 8 and the other with Windows 8.1 and it ran the same (crashed). Both are Python 2.7.5. I need to use this version so I can use ArcGIS (arcpy) libraries with it. I don't think it's the arcpy libraries because the type of the variables are unicode, and it's just doing a basic compare.

Comment: If you can come up with an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) that fails for you, it would dramatically increase the chances that we'll be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: If I copy the values into a string and run it in an isolated script, it works fine. Is there any way printing the variable doesn't show everything? I'll try to recreate the issue in a standalone script.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor object in the original for loop is created from a SearchCursor using arcpy (ArcGIS 10.2.2 python libraries: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000v00000001000000).

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(localMain, ['Main_ID', 'OBJECTID', 'SegmentID', 'Shape@JSON'], where) as cursor:
```

When I print the row from the cursor, I get the following value:

```
(None, 1007, u'{714215DE-7E54-4E3E-8078-3C90E5407237}', <nil>)
```

The Shape@JSON returns `<nil>`, which is causing the error. Although I wasn't interacting with the nil value in the tuple, it was causing the problem. If I did interact with it by trying to print row[3], it would cause python to crash.

The issue was bad data coming in from a 3rd party package.